# Is it possible to share memory between the main and the render process in Electron?

Tags: electron, shared-memory, sharedarraybuffer

I'm working on an application that needs to transfer lots of binary data (chunks of 10-100 MB) as fast as possible, and the ipc api and/or http requests are simply not fast enough (~50-200 MB/s). The best would be to share memory to make it nearly instant. The render process only need to read and not write, if that changes anything.

I have tried SharedArrayBuffer (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770369/use-sharearraybuffer-from-an-electron-app)) but I get the error "Error: An object could not be cloned."

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you have your main process "save" the data to the local file system and then instruct the render process (via IPC) to read the data?